# C# Listview Item Text Orientation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview, orientation

I'm designing an application using a Listview container with LargeIcons as the view type.  I need a way to change the text orientation of the Listview Items with respect to the icon.

For example:
I would like to have to text displayed to the right of the icon in the Listview container.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks,
-Sean!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to achieve this?

```
[    ]
[icon] Text
[    ]
```

If so, it sounds like you need `View.Tile` instead of `View.LargeIcon`.

Comment: Hey Tim, thanks for your quick response!  That's exactly what I needed to do.